# nstart for k-means in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, centroid

Search results in numerous places report that the argument `nstart` in R's function `kmeans` sets a number of iterations of the algorithm and chooses 'the best one', see e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/k-means-in-r-usage-of-nstart-parameter. Can anyone provide any clarity on *how* it does this, i.e. by what measure does it define best?

Secondly: R's `kmeans` function takes an argument `centers`. Here, as typical in k-means, it is possible to initialise the centroids before the algorithm begins expectation-maximisation, by choosing as initial centroids rows (data-points) from within your data-set. (You could supply, in vector form, points *not* present in your data-set as well, with considerably greater effort. In this case you could in theory choose the global optimum as your centroids. This is **not** what I'm asking for.) When `nstart` or the seed randomises initializations, I am quite sure that it does so by picking a random choice of centroids from your data-set and starting from those (not just a random set of points within the space).

In general, therefore, I'm looking for a way to get a good (e.g. best out of $n$ trials, or best from `nstart`) set of starting data-instances **from the data-set** as initial centroids. Is there any way of extracting the 'winning' (=best) set of initial centroids from `nstart` (which I could then use, say, in the `centers` parameter in future)? Any other streamlined & quick way to get a very good set of starting centroids (presumably, reasonably close to where the cluster centres will end up being)?

Is there perhaps, at least, a way to extract from a given `kmeans` run, what initial centroids it chose to start with?

Answer (score 1):

The criterion that kmeans tries to minimize is the trace of the within scatter matrix, i.e. (unfortunately, this forum does not support LaTeX, but you hopefully can read it nevertheless):

$$ trace(S_w) = \sum_{k=1}^K \sum{x \in C_k} ||x - \mu_k||^2 $$

Concerning the best starting point: obviously, the "best" starting point would be the cluster centers eventually chosen by *kmeans*. These are returned in the attribute *centers*:

```
km <- kmeans(iris[,-5], 3)
print(km$centers)
```

If you are looking for the best random start point, you can create random start points yourself (with *runif*), do this *nstart* times and evaluate which initial configuration leads to the smallest *km$tot.withinss*:

```
nstart <- 10
K <- 3 # number of clusters
D <- 4 # data point dimension

# select possible range
r.min <- apply(iris[,-5], MARGIN=2, FUN=min)
r.max <- apply(iris[,-5], MARGIN=2, FUN=max)

for (i in 1:nstart) {
  centers <- data.frame(runif(K, r.min[d], r.max[d]))
  for (d in 2:D) {
    centers <- cbind(centers, data.frame(runif(K, r.min[d], r.max[d])))
  }
  names(centers) <- names(iris[,-5])

  # call kmeans with centers and compare tot.withinss
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. So ```nstart``` will choose the solution which gives the best trace of within scatter matrix, I take it. Can the final value(s) of this trace be returned?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure the second point really answers my question--I'm asking how to choose or find a good set of starting-centres from *my data* as initialisation centroids. (So that, with a good benchmark that will converge quickly to an optimum solution, I can measure how many iterations are necessary or differences between algorithms etc.) Of course it would be overkill to start with the ultimate centroids as then the algorithm wouldn't even need to run, but we can assume these centroids would not be exactly identical to any data-points.

Comment: @moebeus-zoom "Can the final value(s) of this trace be returned? " According to the kmeans documentation, a number of *sum of squares* (postfix *ss*) are returned. The trace of the within scatter matrix shoud be *tot.withinss*.

Comment: Your second question is unclear: what do you mean by a "good set of starting-centres"? In a Monte-Carlo approach, thes are chosen at random. If incidentally these random choice is the global minimum configuration, then this is a good (actually: the very *best*) starting point with the minimum number of iterations (exactly one). If you want poorer guesses, simply add noise to the result returned by kmeans.

Comment: Let me elaborate on this in the main post-- thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, by which you have answered your own question, because you mentioned that the socend parameter of *kmeans* can be the initial cluster centers. I have extended my answer above.

Comment: Thank you, your edit is helpful! Could you add some code? I'm not sure how to implement ```runif``` in the way you suggest.

Comment: @mobeus-zoom "Could you add some code". Done. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, when this actually answers your question (if it does not, I am at aloss).